# Is this the correct way of using YOLO for image classification in a custom project?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, yolo

I'm a beginner in computer vision. Could anyone tell me whether what I'm considering to do is correct or not? I wanted to detect a certain cyst in teeth. So my dataset consists of a part of the dental x-ray that contains that cyst. I train my model with these pictures. The one with the colored area contains cyst (infected teeth), and the one below it is the uninfected teet.
[Image with cyst](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AMly.png)

[Uninfected teeth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2GkT.png)

After training my model, I want to use it on a full dental x-ray, and determine if this picture has the cyst or not. A full dental x-ray is shown below.
[Full dental X-Ray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAc70.png)

Does this work? Or I'm completely wrong?

Comment: Can you share a full dental x-ray with a highlighted cyst?

Comment: @AniketBote here it is. https://pasteboard.co/JogpbLV.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of treating this as an object detection problem, you would get far better results if you were to treat this as a classification problem.
There are already various architectures for such classification tasks.

There are various architectures in TensorFlow to get you started.

Take a look at [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications). If you have enough data you can train them from scratch instead of using pre-trained weights

Note - The architecture provided in TensorFlow will almost always give you better results than the architectures that you create.

Object detection is suitable for cases where you have well-defined objects. If you take a look at recently published research papers you can see that these types of problems are considered as classification problems instead of object detection problems.

Comment: Yes, I agree that treating it as a classification problem is better. I will check the link you provided.